# Date/Time Picker in Swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode, datetimepicker, uidatepicker, picker

How would I make a Time/Date Picker that allows a selection of minutes and seconds and set that as a countdown time (I only need to know how to make the Time/Date Picker). I've found many tutorials but they are made in the Main.storyboard. I want to add it to my GameScene.swift (file type is Cocoa Touch Class). I am working with Swift 4 in Xcode 9.3 in a Game type application.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can make one yourself using `UIPickerView`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want minutes and seconds picker. So, default UIDatePicker does not provide this functionality. So, I have make custom picker using UIPickerView.

1) First, write this code in viewDidLoad() method.

```
    let timePicker: UIPickerView = UIPickerView()
    //assign delegate and datasoursce to its view controller
    timePicker.delegate = self
    timePicker.dataSource = self

    // setting properties of the pickerView
    timePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 200)
    timePicker.backgroundColor = .white

    // add pickerView to the view
    self.view.addSubview(timePicker)
```

2) Second, make extension of your viewcontroller and give them UIPickerViewDelegate and UIPickerViewDataSource as I have done below.

```
extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource{

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return 60
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return String(format: "%02d", row)
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if component == 0{
            let minute = row
            print("minute: \(minute)")
        }else{
            let second = row
            print("second: \(second)")
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.